# Get missing fields on mongoose scheme

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get a count of all the missing or empty fields in mongoose schema

The idea is to have a list of all the properties in a mongoose schema that are blank or does not have a value, so I can make a function to know what percentage of the document is missing.

I tried with count and count by null, but i don't know the query to get the results.

Comment: Is this operation doing this in the application code instead of in the database level acceptable?

Comment: Application level, i mean code using mongoose and nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function like this in your application code:

```
const getDocumentCompleteness = (doc) => {
  const totaFieldCount = Object.keys(doc).length;
  let completedFieldCount = 0;
  for(let key in doc) {
    if(doc[key] !== undefined && doc[key] !== null && doc[key] !== '') {
      completedFieldCount += 1;
    }
  }
  return [totaFieldCount, completedFieldCount];
}
```

Whenever you need to get the completeness of a document, you can do this:

```
const [totaFieldCount, completedFieldCount] = getDocumentCompleteness(document);
// where document is the object representing the document you got from the database
```

I hope that helps.